# Disparity maps in light field images not only stereo-based vision but multiple views

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, disparity-mapping, 4d, multiple-views

I would like to ask about disparity maps in context of **multiple views** (captured by horizontal and vertical cameras). I understood that disparity map is the difference of the pixel location between a pair of views in stereo-based images.
I am intersted in Light field images such as in this link : http://clim.inria.fr/Datasets/InriaSynLF/index.html

what does the disparity exactly mean here, since all the views have a disparity values and I did not understand if there is a reference image and if so why all the views have disparity (I was expecting a reference view to have zero disparity with respect to itself)
Am I missing something?

One more question, if I have all the disparity maps for all views, how can I project a pixel from one view to another view using disparity in this case?

any help in understanding this concept is really appreciated,